# Chaining class decorators to extend game item's abilities

Tags: python, class, design-patterns, decorator

I'm coding a little game for my python course, and I want to integrate an inventory and item system. The possibilities offered by the item are variables (weapons, quest item, consumable or not, an so on).

I have read this tutorial (in French) about the [pattern decorator](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/le-pattern-decorator-en-python) ([google translated in english](http://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffr.openclassrooms.com%2Finformatique%2Fcours%2Fle-pattern-decorator-en-python&act=url)) and I came with this:
(I am using python3)

```
class Item(object):

    def __init__(self, caracts=None, inventory=None):
        self.caracts = {}
        if caracts:
            self.caracts = caracts
        self.inventory = inventory


class ItemDecorator(Item):

    def __init__(self, item):
        super().__init__()
        self.item = item
        self.caracts = item.caracts


class Consumable(ItemDecorator):

    def __init__(self, item, amount=1):
        super().__init__(item)
        self._amount = 0
        self.amount = amount

    @property
    def amount(self):
        return self._amount

    @amount.setter
    def amount(self, value):
        self._amount = max(0, value)
        if self._amount == 0 and self.item.inventory:
            self.item.inventory.remove(self)

    @amount.deleter
    def amount(self):
        del self._amount


class Usable(ItemDecorator):

    def __init__(self, item, action=None, consumable=None):
        if not action:
            action = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
        self._use = action
        self.consumable = consumable

    def use(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.consumable and self.consumable.amount <= 0:
            raise CantBeUsedException("There is no consumable")
        else:
            if self.consumable:
                self.consumable.amount -= 1
            self._use(*args, **kwargs)
```

My idea is to be able to do this:

```
potion = Usable(Consumable(Item(), 3), use_potion)
print("isinstance(potion.item, Consumable): {}".format(
    isinstance(potion.item, Consumable)))
potion.consumable = potion.item
for dummy in range(4):
    try:
        potion.use()
    except CantBeUsedException as e:
        print("Expected exception: {}".format(e))
```

But here comes my issue, line 4. The consumable used by the usable `potion` should be `potion` itself. But `potion` lost its consumable ability and only `potion.item` has it. It's even worst, because the order in which I call my decorator matters. `potion = Consumable(Usable(Item(), use_potion), 3)` leads me to do `potion.item.use()`, always this item that annoys me.

How can I simplify this? Knowing that a usable doesn't necessarily consume itself, or even something. In fact, I would like to be able to do this, no matter which decorator was called first:

```
potion = Consumable(Usable(Item(), use_potion), 3)
potion.consumable = potion
potion.use()
```

I don't manage to found a clean solution for my issue. Here is all the questions that come to my mind:
* Is this Decorator pattern adapted? (It looks so to my mind, but I can be wrong)
    * If it's not the case, to your mind, wouldn't be an interface system (thus, with multiple heritage) a better solution?
* What did I do wrong to get stuck here?

- How can I make this system really simple while still being extensible. For this, I think about this solution:

  ```
  class ItemDecorator(Item):

          def __init__(self, item):
          super().__init__()
          self.item = item
          self.caracts = item.caracts
          if hasattr(item, "amount"):
              self.amount = item.amount
          if hasattr(item, "use"):
              self.use = item.use
  ```

  But by doing so, don't I lose all the extensibility of the Decorator pattern? Indeed, I would need to update ItemDecorator each time I want to create a quite complex decorator. Thus, wouldn't I lose all the advantage of the decorator pattern?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your classes layout is rather twisted, and `Usable(Consumable(Item(), 3), use_potion)` doesn't look pythonic.

I'd slightly redesign the system:

```
class ItemCapability:
    pass


class Consumable(ItemCapability):
    def __init__(self, amount):
        super().__init__()
        self.amount = amount


class Usable(ItemCapability):
    pass


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.capabilities = {}

    def make(self, capability):
        assert isinstance(capability, ItemCapability)
        assert capability.__class__ not in self.capabilities

        self.capabilities[capability.__class__] = capability

    def has(self, capability_cls):
        try:
            return self.capabilities[capability_cls]
        except KeyError:
            return False


potion = Item('potion')
potion.make(Usable())
potion.make(Consumable(amount=10))

print(potion.has(Usable))
print(potion.has(Consumable))
```

This way you have a very simple to understand class system, and easy way to query your items for capabilities.

Comment: The issue is that I can't do easily potion.use() this way. The best I have found is to do `if potion.has(Usable): potion.get(Usable).use()`. It doesn't look really pythonic either.

Comment: In addition to that, if I create the `Weapon` class that inherits from Usable, if I do `gun = Item().make(Weapon(compatible_ammo="9mm"))`, and then `gun.has(Usable)` I would get `False` though Weapon is a usable.

Comment: Can't see the problem with `if .has: .get`. As for the inheritance, you can modify the 'has' method to traverse the `__mro__` of `.capabilities` keys to support inheritance (and that's easily cacheable, btw.